# AWS CDK is giving an error EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I followed below steps to install AWS CDK

> npm install -g aws-cdk

This helps to install aws-cdk in my machine.
Command cdk --version is showing the correct installed version.
However when I use any other cdk command, it throws EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read error.

If found many questions on stackoverflow with same error, which is specific to node.

Here I am confused as I can run any app.js ( Hello world program ) file using using node. which runs perfectly fine. That means nodejs is ok.

The -verbose output of "cdk ls -v" as below

```
D:\Users\ykumar>cdk ls -v
CDK toolkit version: 1.113.0 (build 61e1f65)
Command line arguments: {
  _: [ 'ls' ],
  v: 1,
  verbose: 1,
  lookups: true,
  'ignore-errors': false,
  ignoreErrors: false,
  json: false,
  j: false,
  debug: false,
  ec2creds: undefined,
  i: undefined,
  'version-reporting': undefined,
  versionReporting: undefined,
  'path-metadata': true,
  pathMetadata: true,
  'asset-metadata': true,
  assetMetadata: true,
  'role-arn': undefined,
  r: undefined,
  roleArn: undefined,
  staging: true,
  'no-color': false,
  noColor: false,
  fail: false,
  long: false,
  l: false,
  '$0': 'AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\aws-cdk\\bin\\cdk'
}
merged settings: {
  versionReporting: true,
  pathMetadata: true,
  output: 'cdk.out',
  context: {},
  debug: false,
  assetMetadata: true,
  toolkitBucket: {},
  staging: true,
  bundlingStacks: [],
  lookups: true
}
Determining if we're on an EC2 instance.
Looks like an EC2 instance.
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Comment: I get the same thing and am also getting it with npx cdk ls

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.  I don't know how it happened, but I use aws sso login not the ~/.aws/credentials file and somehow ~/.aws/credentials was a directory not a file and this was causing the error

Comment: Thanks! For me it was `~/.aws/config` that was a folder for some reason.